# How do I host a new app to Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

This has newbie written all over it. I have  Angularjs deployed to firebase, Now I want to deploy another.  Do I start from my Dashboard and create new app, for do i first do firebase Init on the directory where the Index, html file is located? The documentation seems to indicate that we startwith Firebase Init command. If so, what is the Create New app on the dashboard used or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new directory for your new AngularJS app. Be sure that neither of these directories is nested under the other, since that won't work.
2. Put the HTML, CSS, JS and whatever files in that directory
3. Create a new app from your Firebase dashboard
4. Run `firebase init` in the directory
5. Select the new app you just created

From then on, run `firebase deploy` as you usually would.

Comment: Thank you Frank.. worked, but found that I could not create the new directory as a subdirectory of a directory that already included a firebase.json file.  But the app is live. Thanks